# Deactive the :terminal command

Tags: neovim

I am very often typing `:Te` and use tab to auto complete this value to `:Texplore`. However, when I misstype to `:te`, it will autocomplete to `:terminal`, which opens a terminal in the current buffer, so I am losing my currently opened file, which is really a pain.

Also, I am using nvim in tmux, so there is actually no need for me to use the terminal emulator included in nvim. So I was wondering if there is some option to disable or remove the `:terminal` command, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why not make a mapping if you’re doing it so often? `<Leader>T` strikes me as one appropriate choice

Comment: Because it is hard to change habbits :-) And also because I really never want to open the terminal in vim, no matter in what circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to disable built-in commands but you can use `:cabbr` to map `:te` to `:Texplore`: `cabbr te Texplore`.

Also note that on normal mode on any buffer (including the terminal) you can press `Ctrl-^` to go back to the previous one

Comment: That's not really satisfying :-/ But the `Ctrl-^` workaround is awesome, might also be handy in other situations :-D